# How to convert code that written in traditional asp.net way to asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on project that manage inventory.
I have written it on simple asp.net way means I add element on .aspx file and backend code write in c#.
But now I want to convert it to MVC.

Comment: Please precisely describe what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easy: You need to learn asp.net MVC!